# MDX Sum values from current month

Tags: sql-server, sum, mdx, cube

I have the problem with `SUM` query.
I want to sum the 'zaplata' from every month, but always I get the sum of all years...

MDX query:

```
with member [Zapl] as 
   'Sum(
      [Data Zameldowania].[Sprzątanie w dany typ dnia], 
      [Measures].[Zaplata - Sprzatanie]
    )'
select
   non empty 
      {[Data Zameldowania].[Sprzątanie w dany typ dnia].[Miesiac Slownie]} on 0,
   non empty 
      {[Measures].[Liczba gosci],[Zapl]} on 1
from [Hurtownia Danych]
where 
    [Data Zameldowania].[Data sprzątania].[Rok].&[2012];
```

This is what I get from my MDX Query: 
[image]

This is what I have in Data Warehouse (SQL qyery from DW shows that in MDX query i get sum of all 'zaplata'. I want to sum 'zaplata' of each mont):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to create the new measures `member` [Zapl] ? Does this not work?

```
select
   non empty 
      {[Data Zameldowania].[Sprzątanie w dany typ dnia].[Miesiac Slownie]} on 0,
   non empty 
      { [Measures].[Liczba gosci]
       ,[Measures].[Zaplata - Sprzatanie] } on 1
from [Hurtownia Danych]
where 
    [Data Zameldowania].[Data sprzątania].[Rok].&[2012];
```